# How to set WizardForm to be full screen in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, fullscreen

I would like to make new installer with `WizardForm.Width` is width of user monitor width and `WizardForm.Height` is height of user monitor height.

So, I already wrote new code, but there is one error like some black area.

[image: like in this picture below]

This is my code that I have compiled:

```pascal
[Code]
function GetSystemMetrics(nIndex:Integer):Integer;
external 'GetSystemMetrics@user32.dll stdcall';

procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  width,height: Integer;
begin
  MainForm.BorderStyle:= bsNone;
  width:= GetSystemMetrics(0);
  height:= GetSystemMetrics(1);
  MainForm.Width:= width;
  MainForm.Height:= height;
  width:= MainForm.ClientWidth;
  height:= MainForm.ClientHeight;
  MainForm.Left := 0;
  MainForm.Top := 0;

  WizardForm.Position:= poScreenCenter;
  WizardForm.BorderStyle:= bsNone;
  WizardForm.Width:= MainForm.Width;
  WizardForm.Height:= MainForm.Height;
  WizardForm.ClientWidth:= MainForm.ClientWidth;
  WizardForm.ClientHeight:= MainForm.ClientHeight;
  MainForm.Visible:= True;
end;
```

Comment: tbqh I would find that pretty annoying, is there a reason you need to do it? Its very 1990s

Comment: Why do you display the `MainForm`, when you stretch the `WizardForm` over whole screen? Anyway, I agree with Alex.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why you engage with `MainForm`. Just resize the `WizardForm`.

```pascal
[Code]

function GetSystemMetrics(nIndex: Integer): Integer;
  external 'GetSystemMetrics@user32.dll stdcall';

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  WizardForm.Position := poScreenCenter;
  WizardForm.BorderStyle := bsNone;
  WizardForm.Width := GetSystemMetrics(0);
  WizardForm.Height := GetSystemMetrics(1);
end;
```

Though the wizard is not designed to be stretched over whole screen anyway.